# When I run a Jenkins code, I get a console output error

Tags: jenkins

I don't understand what's wrong with this code, when I run it, I'm getting a console output error. The error image is given below, I would appreciate an answer on what to do.

```
  pipeline {
    
        agent any    
       
        stages{
    
            stage('Git checkout'){
    
    
                steps{
    
                    script{
                    gitCheckout(
                        branch: "development",
                        url: "https://github.com/TECHNOOXYSERVICE/ReportRepo.git"
                    )
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('gradle build'){
    
                steps{
    
                    script{
    
                        sh """
                         cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon
                         ./gradle clean build
                         ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('second file gradle build'){
    
                 steps{
    
                     script{
    
                         sh """
                         cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwsaudit
                         ./gradlew clean build
                         ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
                         """
                   }
              }
        }
                   
            stage('third file gradle build'){
    
                steps{
    
                    script{
                       
                        sh """
                         cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscore
                         ./gradle clean build
                         ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                        """
    
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('fourth file gradle build'){
    
                steps{
    
                    script{
                       
                        sh """
                         cd cws/ReportRepo/th.cws
                         ./gradle clean build
                         ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                        """
    
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('file gradle build'){
    
                steps{
    
                    script{
                       
                        sh """
                         cd cws-batch-api-ms
                         ./gradle clean build
                         ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                         cd cws-batch-api-ms/build/l
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
         }
     }
```

[image: Error:]

Thanks in advance, also, I would appreciate it if I could know what the problem was for the code, so I could implement it in the future!

Comment: what's the error? I don't see anything wrong with the screenshot of the console you shared. Can you please provide full logs? Thanks